# Icon Wrong Animation when button tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, button, swiftui

I'm having issues with button selection. I'm using an enum to keep track of the pages within the app and their values like Page Title and Page Icon. I use these values to create a menu with buttons inside a VStack. I retrieve all the enum values (AppScreen) using ForEach and populate them into the buttons' labels. So far, so good, but when I select a button, the icon animation affects the previously selected button as well. Let me provide an example:

The titles of my buttons are "Button 1" and "Button 2" with their associated icons. When I select "Button 1," the icon animation works perfectly, but when I select "Button 2," it doesn't work correctly because it animates both the icons of "Button 1" and "Button 2" instead of just "Button 2."

Where am I going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation

enum AppScreen: CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case btn1, btn2
    
    var id: AppScreen { self }
    
    var screenName: String {
        switch self {
        case .btn1: "btn1"
        case .btn2: "btn2"
        }
    }
    
    var screenIcon: String {
        switch self {
        case .btn1: "exclamationmark.arrow.triangle.2.circlepath"
        case .btn2: "person.2"
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct AppSideBar: View {
@Binding var appScreen: AppScreen?
@State private var selection: String = ""

var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(AppScreen.allCases) { screen in
                    Button {
                        selection = screen.screenName
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: screen.screenIcon)
                                
                            Text(screen.screenName)
                                .foregroundStyle(selection == screen.screenName ? .red : .white)
                        }
                    }
                    .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: selection == screen.screenName)
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                }
            }
        }
#if os(macOS)
.frame(width: NSScreen.main!.visibleFrame.width / 1.6, 
       height: NSScreen.main!.visibleFrame.height - 100)
#endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/symboleffect(_:options:value:)) for `.symbolEffect` states that the "the animation is triggered each time the value changes". So it is triggered when the condition changes from false to true, but it is also triggered when it changes from true to false.

To fix, I think you need separate flags for each button and a flag should only change when the selection is being applied, not when the selection is moving away. Like this:

```swift
@State private var selectionApplied = [AppScreen: Bool]()
```

```swift
ForEach(AppScreen.allCases) { screen in
    Button {
        let wasApplied = selectionApplied[screen] ?? false
        selectionApplied[screen] = !wasApplied
        selection = screen.screenName
    } label: {
        // as before
    }
    .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: selectionApplied[screen] ?? false)
    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
}
```

Comment: forgive me, I wrote the code wrong... everything works perfectly thanks to your suggestion.. thanks for your support